# Trouble registering an ETW Provider

Tags: c#, etw, c#-6.0, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a UWP based application for Windows 10 IoT and I am wanting to configure ETW Tracing so I can view logging remotely using the integrated web interface:

[image: ETW List]

I believe I have created the necessary types, however I cannot see my provider in any of the lists shown within the IoT ETW section:

[image: ETW Options]

My **EventListener** implementation is:

```
sealed class StorageFileEventListener : EventListener
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Storage file to be used to write logs 
    /// </summary> 
    private StorageFile _mStorageFile = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Name of the current event listener 
    /// </summary> 
    private readonly string _mName;

    public StorageFileEventListener(string name)
    {
        _mName = name;

        Debug.WriteLine("StorageFileEventListener for {0} has name {1}", GetHashCode(), name);

        AssignLocalFile();
    }

    private async void AssignLocalFile()
    {
        _mStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(_mName.Replace(" ", "_") + ".log",
                                                                                  CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    }

    private async void WriteToFile(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        // TODO: 
    }

    protected override void OnEventWritten(EventWrittenEventArgs eventData)
    {
        // TODO: 
    }

    protected override void OnEventSourceCreated(EventSource eventSource)
    {
        // TODO: 
    }
}
```

My **EventSource** implementation is:

```
internal sealed class Logger : EventSource
{
    public static Logger Log = new Logger();

    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Verbose)]
    public void Debug(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = GenerateExceptionMessage(exception);
        WriteEvent(1, message + exceptionMessage);
    }

    [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Info(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = GenerateExceptionMessage(exception);
        WriteEvent(2, message + exceptionMessage);
    }

    [Event(3, Level = EventLevel.Warning)]
    public void Warn(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = GenerateExceptionMessage(exception);
        WriteEvent(3, message + exceptionMessage);
    }

    [Event(4, Level = EventLevel.Error)]
    public void Error(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = GenerateExceptionMessage(exception);
        WriteEvent(4, message + exceptionMessage);
    }

    [Event(5, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
    public void Critical(string message, Exception exception)
    {
        var exceptionMessage = GenerateExceptionMessage(exception);
        WriteEvent(5, message + exceptionMessage);
    }

    private static string GenerateExceptionMessage(Exception exception)
    {
        return exception != null ? $" Exception message - {exception.Message} :: InnerException - {exception.InnerException} :: StackTrace - {exception.StackTrace}" 
                                    : "";
    }
}
```

Finally, I initialise and configure my EventSource/EventListener types like so:

```
        EventListener genericListener = new StorageFileEventListener("MyIoTListener");
        genericListener.EnableEvents(Logger.Log, EventLevel.Critical);
```

Am I missing a fundamental step?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution for making the source appear on the custom provider list, but does provide access to the events from the web interface.  Just type in the GUID of the EventSource into the custom providers text box.

On the phone, I have a C# UWP app with the following event source, (copied from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/12/20/an-end-to-end-etw-tracing-example-eventsource-and-traceevent/))

```
    [EventSource(Guid = "{GUID of EventSource}", Name = "SourceName")] 
    class MyEventSource : EventSource
    {
        public void MyEvent(string msg, int id) { WriteEvent(1, msg, id); }

        public static MyEventSource Log = new MyEventSource();
    }
```

I'm using the Windows Device Portal API ([described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core)), and use the following process in my desktop app to read events:

1. Connect a web socket to **ws://127.0.0.1:10080/api/etw/session/realtime**
2. Send **"provider {GUID of EventSource} enable 5"**
3. ...Read events,
4. Send **"provider {GUID of EventSource} disable"**

This all works well and good, however, when I query **http://127.0.0.1:10080/api/etw/customproviders**, the list is still empty.

On the desktop platform I understand one uses [wevtutil.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848(v=ws.11).aspx):

```
wevtutil.exe im {App-Manifest}.man
```

for a similar purpose, but don't know if it applies to windows mobile.

Comment: Since EventSource generates the GUID from the name, you have to use https://github.com/jonwagner/EventSourceProxy/wiki/Getting-the-EventSource-Manifest-or-GUID to get the GUID